# action Cmd+Return does not emit shortcut override event on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I found a probable bug in Qt. But before I report it as a bug, I would like to ask here just in case someone knows any simple workaround or any credible explanation for this to be a feature rather than a bug... Unfortunately it is quite complicated to describe.

---

Short story:

If an action with `Cmd+Return` shortcut is present in the main application menu, then an event with type `QEvent::ShortcutOverride` is not invoked when this shortcut is pressed. The problem seems to be on **macOS** only, the corresponding `Ctrl+Return` works well on **Windows** and **Linux**. The problem curiously does not exist if the action is not present in the main menu or is disabled. This problem also does not exist for many other 'innocent' shortcuts such as `Cmd+R`, `Cmd+I`, etc.

The consequence of problem this is that you cannot override the application-wide `Cmd+Return` shortcut and handle this shortcut locally in a widget by handling its corresponding key press event.

---

Long story:

In an application, I have a `QTextEdit` and I want to implement `Cmd+Return` key press event to submit the edited text. To achieve this I installed event filter for this text edit and handle `Cmd+Return` key press event in the event filter.

But it solution alone does not work because in my application I also happen to have some global application-wide shortcut `Cmd+Enter` in the main menu which is reserved for some other operation. So my next step was to override this global application shortcut using the event filter and handling `QEvent::ShortcutOverride` by calling `event->setAccepted(true)`. This way I should be able to force the application to ignore the global shortcut and handle the shortcut locally in the event filter's key press event handler. At least this works for all other shortcuts for which I have conflicts between global shortcut and local handler.

But as I found this does not work for `Cmd+Return` on macOS and the `ShortcutOverride` event is not invoked for this very specific shortcut. Curiously it works for `Ctrl+Return` on Windows and Linux. And curiously it works for other shortcuts such as `Cmd+R`, `Cmd+I`.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <QAction>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QTextEdit>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        auto menu = new QMenu("Menu");
        auto menuBar = new QMenuBar();
        menuBar->addMenu(menu);
        setMenuBar(menuBar);

        auto action1 = new QAction("Action 1");
        action1->setShortcut({Qt::CTRL | Qt::Key_Return}); // evil "unblockable" shortcut
        menu->addAction(action1);
        connect(action1, &QAction::triggered, this, []{ qDebug() << "action 1"; } );

        auto action2 = new QAction("Action 2");
        action2->setShortcut({Qt::CTRL | Qt::Key_R}); // innocent "blockable" shortcut
        menu->addAction(action2);
        connect(action2, &QAction::triggered, this, []{ qDebug() << "action 2"; } );

        auto textEdit = new QTextEdit();
        setCentralWidget(textEdit);
        textEdit->installEventFilter(this);
    }

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::ShortcutOverride)
        {
            // setting as accepted blocks the global shortcut
            auto keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
            qDebug() << "shortcut override" << keyEvent;
            event->setAccepted(true); 
            return true;
        }

        if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            // this is the local key shortcut handler
            auto keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
            qDebug() << "key press" << keyEvent;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

If I press `Cmd+R` then "key press QKeyEvent(KeyPress, Key_R, ControlModifier)" is printed. In other words, I am able to handle `Cmd+R` in the key press event handler in the event filter.

But if I press `Cmd+Return` then "action 1" is printed. I.e. there is no chance to handle this shortcut in key press handler in the event filter.

The reason is however that "ShortcutOverride" event was not invoked for `Cmd+Return` and hence it could not be set as accepted. Unlike for `Cmd+R`.

---

Conclusion:

My workaround solution will be to disable the global application-wide shortcut in the main menu when the focus is on the text edit. It seems to solve the problem. But this is a very unpleasant refactoring because enabling and disabling of application-wide menu actions have quite a lot of consequences in the whole application.

Does anyone know any other more "local" hack or trick to make this shortcut overriding work?

And is it a bug or not? If feels like one to me.

---

Update:

I created a bug ticket for this https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-107526

Comment: Not sure if it solves the problem completely but, on my own macbook changing `Qt::Key_Return` to `Qt::Key_Enter` appears to give the desired behaviour.

Comment: Instead of installing an event filter in your `QTextEdit`, you could install it in the global `QApplication` instance. (Of course, you have to check the passed `QObject*` whether it's for your `QTextEdit`.) AFAIK, this is earlier called when the event filter for specific widgets. (This is aside of the fact that `Qt::Key_Return` and `Qt::Key_Enter` address two different keys on the keyboard.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I am not sure if I understand. The problem with installing event filter on `QApplication` is that I do want to override the global shortcut event by local key press event handler ONLY when the focus is in the text edit. In all other cases I want the global shortcut to remain active.

Comment: @G.M. Well, I found a problem with changing `Return` to `Enter`... because then the global action will never get triggered by pressing actual `Return` key on my MacBook. So I would be overriding a non-existent shortcut. So this does not provide a solution unfortunately.

Comment: Concerning _ONLY when the focus is in the text edit._ This is still no problem. It could be checked in your event filter as well. As long as the event filter returns `false` the event is passed down the "event processing pipeline" to be handled elsewhere. Actually, you could install the event filter in the `focusInEvent()` (as well as remove that event filter in the `focusOutEvent()`) so that filtering doesn't happen as long as the `QTextEdit` doesn't have the focus. (Considering that a global filter is called for _every_ event for every widget, this couldn't hurt.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and was fixed inn Qt 6.4.3. See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-107526